# Macbeth or MacBeth (and other Scottish surnames)?

Tags: orthography

I get the impression that names beginning with Mac generally seem to be followed by a capital, and yet Macbeth doesn’t. Is that impression correct, and why the variation?

Answer (score 6):

No, other Scottish surnames are found without a capital after the ‘Mac’, and even Macbeth is sometimes spelled as MacBeth.

I am more fortunate than some in having a first-hand opportunity to research the subject. Here is a listing (probably not publicly available) of some of the first few Glasgow University staff surnames beginning with Mac or Mc:

> Macalister, McAlister
>
> Macallan, McAllan
>
> MacArthur, Macarthur, McArthur
>
> Macartney
>
> Macaulay, McAulay
>
> Macbride, McBride
>
> McBeth
>
> MacDonald, McDonald
>
> Macdougall, McDougall

The only pattern is that names beginning with ‘Mc’ are followed by a capital, presumably because it is an abbreviation and cannot be spoken as a word. The rest is custom. There may be some surnames that are always MacCapital and some that are never, but there isn’t any rule that I am aware of. Other answers discuss the origin of ‘Mac’ and the anglicisation of these surnames.

And what about Macbeth? Well this [James MacBeth](https://www.autowindscreens.co.uk/news/james-macbeth-becomes-operations-director/102154.aspx) would probably blame Shakespeare (or was it [Shakspere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spelling_of_Shakespeare%27s_name)?) as he, for one, appears to differ.

Comment: 'This question is based on an incorrect premise.' is a reason to close-vote rather than answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Is that...universally true? It doesn't even seem true for this particular question, to me, because this *does* answer the question.

Comment: @Kylie Strand 'I am wondering why it is that names beginning with Mac always seem to be followed by a capital and yet Macbeth doesn’t.' is closeable because not a shred of supporting research is posted.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — I don't have the privilege to vote to close and the evidence I posted is too much for a comment. An alternative would be to change the question (and slightly modify the answer) to fit. (Is Macbeth…)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — and I have done what I suggested. I don't think it should offend anyone, and actually makes the other answers more pertinent.

Comment: The edit is certainly an improvement, but questions unaccompanied by reasonable research (perhaps data from a phone directory here) should normally be closed. // Proper names not being part of the lexicon as such, queries about their peculiarities are arguably off-topic here in any case. They'd be fine on certain other websites.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth — As those with close votes at their disposition think fit, but, I do sometimes get the impression of a lack of even-handedness in this regard. And anyone who asks an idiotic question about whether there is a word for something completely unlikey gets away with it, because you aren't expected to search for "tying your shoelaces while thinking about the infinite wonder of the universe".

Comment: If it cheers you up, I retracted my close vote and upvoted the question and your excellent answer.

Comment: There is bound to be a lack of even-handedness because different people look at different questions. There is even partisan rather than truly considered voting.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — Of course. And as one who has argued for adherence to certain other rules, I am in no position to complain. What I would say is that the important thing is the spirit of the law. SE was established to produce an archive of questions and answers that can be of subsequent use to others as well as immediate use to the OP. So, the usefulness of the question and answers should be more important than whether the OP did enough preliminary research.

Answer (score 3):

The spelling Macbeth is the anglicised  form of the medieval Gaelic Mac Bethad:

> - ***[Macbeth](http://www.bbc.co.uk/history/historic_figures/macbeth.shtml), c.1040 Macbeth, c.1040  © Macbeth was a king of the Scots*** whose rule was marked by efficient government and the promotion of Christianity, but who is best known as the murderer and usurper in William Shakespeare's tragedy.
> - Shakespeare's Macbeth bears little resemblance to the real 11th century Scottish king.
> - ***Mac Bethad mac Findláich, known in English as Macbeth*** , was born in around 1005. His father was Finlay, Mormaer of Moray, and his mother may have been Donada, second daughter of Malcolm II. A 'mormaer' was literally a high steward of one of the ancient Celtic provinces of Scotland, but in Latin documents the word is usually translated as 'comes', which means earl.

(www.bbc.com)

> - ***[Mac Bethad](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macbeth,_King_of_Scotland) mac Findlaích (Modern Gaelic***: MacBheatha mac Fhionnlaigh; ***Medieval Gaelic***: Mac Bethad mac Findlaích; ***anglicised as Macbeth MacFin[d]lay or Macbeth MacFinley,***  and nicknamed Rí Deircc, "the Red King";[1](http://www.bbc.co.uk/history/historic_figures/macbeth.shtml) born c. 1005 - died 15 August 1057) was King of the Scots (also known as the King of Alba, and earlier as King of Moray and King of Fortriu) from 1040 until his death.

(Wiktionary)

It appears there is no clear patter for using a capital letter after the prefix ***[Mc or Mac](http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2014/02/mac-mc-surnames-often-contain-second-capital-letter/)***:

> ***You can probably see why Mc and Mac names typically contain a second capital letter.*** Since proper nouns are capitalized, you would write “son of Donald,” not “son of donald.” In the same way, you would usually write MacDonald rather than Macdonald, ***but there are obviously exceptions.***  Surnames have been around so long that sometimes they get changed, and in some families, the second capital letter was gotten rid of.
>
> - ***In addition, some Mc and Mac names don’t include the name of the father, but the father’s profession***. Take someone named John Macmaster. In this case, John’s father was a master of some sort, therefore John is the “son of a master.” Master is not a proper noun and thus does not need to be capitalized.  This practice can be seen elsewhere—every Smith, Baker, and Cook likely had someone in that occupation somewhere in their ancestry.
> - ***Other Mc and Mac surnames come from some physical feature of the person, such as Macilbowie, which means “son of the blonde man,”*** while the more recognizable Mackenzie (ironically enough now a popular first name for girls) means “son of the fair one.” Again, every Brown, White, Green, Bruin, Weiss, LeBlanc, etc. can relate.

(www.todayifoundout.com)

Comment: I bet MacBheatha is pronounced completely different from how we pronounce Macbeth, probably [mik ˈvʲahə].

Answer (score 0):

"Mac" means son of in Scottish, in this case, the name MacBeth (which is correct) has been anglicized to Macbeth, it could very well be for artistic and poetic purposes.

The character of Macbeth is derived from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macbeth,_King_of_Scotland
whose Scottish name is Mac Bethad.

Comment: _Mac_ doesn’t mean ‘son of’; it just means ‘son’. And _Mac Bethad_ is not Scottish; it is Old or Middle Irish. In modern-day Scottish, it is _Mac Bheatha_. You also don’t answer the actual question of why this particular name was Anglicised (and often even modern-Scotticised) as one word with no interCaps.

Comment: It isn't in 'Scottish' at all, it's in Gaelic.

Comment: Some families capitalise the second element of "Mac" names, some don't. 
Some spell the prefix Mac and some Mc. I don't think there is any logical reason for the variations.

Comment: @Spagirl _Scottish_ is a perfectly acceptable term to use for the language, though it is ambiguous (as it can also refer to Scottish English, or indeed to the various other closely related languages usually labelled Scots). _Gaelic_ is also a perfectly acceptable term, but equally ambiguous (it can also—and outside the UK primarily does—refer to Irish Gaelic, or indeed to Manx Gaelic). The only unambiguous way to refer to it is _Scottish Gaelic_ or _Gàidhlig_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It may be that to irish Gaelic speakers it is perfectly fine, but it isn't usage *in Scotland*. *'But the reality is that the Scots don't call Gaelic "Scottish". They either wouldn't understand that term at all or would think that you were referring to Scots (a very different language). The term they have consistently used for the past two centuries is "Gaelic" and it seems to me that foreigners (whether they hail from Ireland, United States, or elsewhere) should respect their choice in the matter. It's their language after all.'* http://preview.tinyurl.com/k42ojvr

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Given that audiences are mixed I don't take any issue with use of *Scottish Gaelic* or *Gàidhlig*, but for a Scottish audience 'Scottish' is ambiguous at least.

Comment: @Spagirl _Scottish_ is ambiguous everywhere. _Gaelic_ is fairly unlikely to be ambiguous in Scotland (in speech it shouldn’t be ambiguous anywhere of course), but will be everywhere else. Both terms are in use for the language in various contexts, but ideally they shouldn’t be unless context makes them unambiguous.